# Drupal 7 set content type url to custom value

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am using Drupal 7 and have created a custom content type and a view that displays those content types.  What I want to do is override the url to the node in the teaser view.  My specific use case is this:

I have a support view that displays support content types.  When I view that page, I see the teasers for the support content types I have created: Safety, FAQ, Ticketing.  Safety and FAQ link to their nodes as expected.  What I am trying to accomplish, is have the teaser and image for ticketing there, but have it link to my external ticketing portal.  Essentially, I would like to have a checkbox when creating content of this type that allows me to link to external url.  I do have the link module installed, but there is no way for me to apply that field to the url of the title.

I have spent a while googling around trying to find the answer, but without much success.  If there is nothing available to do this already, I wouldn't mind building a module and submitting it to the community.  Just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Here are the steps I took using the answer given below:

1. Install the link module: http://drupal.org/project/link
2. Create a content type, add a field for `link`
3. Add new content of that type and add the url you want to link to in
   the `link` field
4. Create a view and filter by that content type
5. Under format, i'm using `format: "grid"` with `show: "fields"`
6. Add a field for the `Content: link` field you created **FIRST*** in the list. 
   Set to `Exclude from display` and `Formatter: URL, as plain text`
7. Add a title field and deselect "Link this field to the original
   piece of content" click on "rewrite results" and select "rewrite the
   output of this field".  Enter `<a
   href="[field_link_to]">[title]</a>` in the text field where
   `[field_link_to]` is the name of the link field as described in the
   "replacement patterns" dropdown below it.

   - If you do not have the link field in your list of fields FIRST, the token will not be available to the fields below it.
   - In your Content Type > Manage Fields > Link (edit) > Wrapper markup, make sure "no markup" is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the display of the view using the rewrite options. Make sure your display type is set to 'fields'. Then include the fields you want to display; title, teaser, image.

In the field configuration of the title field, choose 'rewrite results'. there you can enter the following `<a href="example.com">[title]</a>` That should overrule the title.

Also make sure to uncheck 'link the field to it's node'.

UPDATE: You might have to create a second view for this... To prevent editing the other two elements.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely pointed me in the right direction.  See my solution steps above

Answer (score 0):

Step 7 is different in Drupal 7.22

1. Title "rewrite results" > select "Output this field as a link" > text field under Link path is only "[field_link_to]" (without `<a href=...>`... etc.)